# Amazon AWS EC2 image shutting itself down

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

We have a Bamboo elastic instance running on Amazon AWS EC2, which is running Windows Server 2008 R2.

There have been multiple times that the instance has shut down automatically. This has occurred both when logged in and when not logged in. There has not appeared to be anything causing the shut down, such as Windows Updates pending.

How can we determine what is causing the instance to automatically shut down?

Comment: Is there anything in the event log?

Comment: Kate, I don't think so. The memory is volatile on EC2, so that whatever changes have not been saved into a new image are lost upon shutdown. So I cannot view the Windows Server log.

Comment: like this http://serverfault.com/questions/257148/ec2-rebooted-my-instance

Comment: Frederico, thanks that might be it. This has been happening every couple of weeks. I wonder if its that frequent I should be expecting such a thing?

Comment: How was your system deployed? Is it in an Auto-scaling group? I've been running servers in EC2 for years, and as a rule, they do not reboot your servers willy-nilly except in cases of hardware failure on the underlying host, or when they're retiring the physical host, which is not what is happening here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it needs to be addressed to AWS support.

Comment: I'm deploying it through Atlassian Bamboo.